# How to authenticate with OAuth for Group Posting

Tags: facebook, oauth, oauth-2.0

To be able to post to a group page I need an oauth access token that lives forever.  Is the only way to do this is to create a Facebook app and use the client-id of it and other parameters to grab this?  How do I give permission to the app to post to the actual group though?  If someone can list the steps on how to do this, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook `access_token` lifecycle (including extension/refresh, etc) are well documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending